# git checkout didn't work

Tags: git, reset, git-checkout

I did backup my files, before a rough `git reset --hard HEAD@{n}` from `git reflog` :'( On **develop** branch.

But, I also lost my files on **master** branch. T__T

I did undoing the reset though, on **develop**. I tried to `git checkout master`, and then pasted the backup files to **master**. After that, I can't go back to **develop** because this message prevent me to:

`(master) $ git checkout develop 
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout: 
    some folder/files
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches. 
Aborting`

**some folder/files** < is from the backed up folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of where you wanna place the backed up files/folders.

1. If you do not want to keep the local changes(your backed up files in this case), you can do `git checkout develop -f`. -f stands for --force and it will throw away your local changes.
2. If you wanna keep the local changes, you can manually copy and paste it somewhere first or you could also use `git stash` to save it(it will automatically revert your changes as well), `git checkout develop` and then `git stash pop` to reapply your changes.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the question sir, I just wanna try to have the "files" that **master** first had in the past *before that `reset` happens. >_< I did changes that "files" but on different branch, that's **develop**. When I've made a mistake, I used `reset` on **develop**, but that `reset`, deleted the files on "any" branch except **develop**.

Comment: Though, I didn't do any local changes for **master**. Is the number 1 suits me well? For this circumtances.

Comment: (it will automatically revert your changes as well)

what do you mean by this?

is the files on **develop** branch will revert as same as **master** has in it?
Or just the current branch, I assumes in this case is **master** branch

Comment: Based on what you are saying, if you haven't committed your changes, you have probably lost all of them(unless you saved them outside of the repo). Anyway, since you mention that there are no changes in master, you can just do a force checkout `git checkout develop -f`

Comment: Yeah, the `git checkout develop -f` allows me to switch branches :) even it my **master** branch, still lose the files though T___T

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

1. move the backed up files back into place
2. `git stash`
3. `git checkout develop`
4. `git stash apply`

What does that yield for you?

Comment: I already "moved" my backup files and do `git stash` but, after I `git checkout develop` and did `git stash apply`. The result is:

`(master) $ git stash`:
`No local changes to save`
`(master) $ git checkout develop`
`(develop) $ git stash apply`:
`No stash found`

Comment: Just curious, are you also pasting the .git folder by mistake?

Comment: No, I didn't paste the **.git** foler. I pasted the folder from my backup my files to root (project1) subdirectory
project1
`├── .git
│   └── etc
└── css
    ├── bla.css
    └── bla1.css`
I put my backup files into css files

Comment: looks like I can't made the "File Organization" in comment T__T